# Unable to access a block which is passed as arguments in this method

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks

In the following example, I have no idea on how to access the block which I passed as parameter in the method. I should have used typedef, but only if I broke the code, I could get the below scenario. So didn't use typedef

```
@interface ViewController ()

- (void(^)(void))  anotherMethodWithReturnTypeAnd: ( void ( ^ )( int ))argumentsBlock;

@end

@implementation ViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

void (^twoBlock)(void) = [ self anotherMethodWithReturnTypeAnd:^(int n) {
    NSLog(@"%d, block without typedef",n);
}];
twoBlock();
}


- (void(^)(void))  anotherMethodWithReturnTypeAnd: ( void ( ^ )( int n) )argumentsBlock{
void (^blockToPassAsReturnType)(void) = ^{
    NSLog(@"Passing this block as return type");
};
return blockToPassAsReturnType;
}
```

OUTPUT:

```
2017-09-05 00:23:08.148 DeleteThisBlockProject[657:22195] Passing this block as return type
```

So how should I use and pass value for the block which I passed as parameter, [ self anotherMethodWithReturnTypeAnd:^(int n) {
        NSLog(@"%d, block without typedef",n);
    }];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't call method

```
@implementation ViewController
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    void (^twoBlock)(void) = [ self anotherMethodWithReturnTypeAnd:^(int n) {
        // this will never execute because you didn't call it you just implemented it
        NSLog(@"%d, block without typedef",n); 
    }];
    twoBlock();
}


- (void(^)(void))  anotherMethodWithReturnTypeAnd: ( void ( ^ )( int n) )argumentsBlock{
    void (^blockToPassAsReturnType)(void) = ^{
        NSLog(@"Passing this block as return type");
    };
    // you should call method which you did provide to this function
    argumentsBlock(yourInt)
    return blockToPassAsReturnType;
}
```

Comment: Got it, I was confused on the syntax.